# how to make loop async in python

Tags: python, asynchronous

```py
async def get_post_from_channel(channel, dateframe):
     try:
         my_channel = await client.get_entity(channel)
     except (ValueError, telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.UsernameInvalidError):
         return 0
     result = []
     utc = pytz.UTC
     async for msg in client.iter_messages(my_channel):
         if msg.date > utc.localize(datetime.datetime.today() - timedelta(dateframe)):
             result.append(msg)
     return len(result)

async def get_posts_num(tg_urls, dateframe):
     post_info = {}
     for i in tg_urls:
         num = await get_post_from_channel(i, dateframe)
         post_info.update({i: num})
         print({i: num})
     with open(f'post_stat{dateframe}.json', 'w') as outfile:
         json.dump(post_info, outfile)
```

I have 2 async functions. The first one is auxiliry and is used in second `get_posts_num` function in loop. I can use a normal for loop but then my code will act synchronously and I lose the benefits and speed of having an async response fetching function.

Is there any way I can convert a list such that the above works? I just need to change the list's **iter**() to a **aiter**() method right? Can this be achieved by subclassing a list? Maybe encapsulating it in a class?

Comment: You're probably looking for the [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently) function.